# Ruby - How do you use a while loop and conditional statement in a 2 Player Dice Game?

Tags: ruby

New to programming and trying to create a very basic two player dice throwing game in Ruby using while loops with conditional breaks.

I need it to play several rounds for each game - the first player to win two rounds wins the game (with two dice each)

So far I have come up with:

```
player_1 = 2 + rand(6) + rand(6) #generates number between 1-12 (simulating two dice being thrown)
player_2 = 2 + rand(6) + rand(6)

puts player_1
puts player_2

player_1_score = 0
player_2_score = 0

while true do
  if player_1 > player_2
    return player_1_score = player_1_score + 1
  elsif player_2 > player_1
    return player_2_score = player_2_score + 1
  end
  if player_1_score == 2
    puts "Player 1 wins!"
    break
  elsif player_2_score == 2
    puts "Player 2 wins!"
    break
  end
end
```

At the moment it is only producing the two random numbers, no error messages. I need to it to produce a number of rounds and either "Player 1 wins!" or "Player 2 wins!" when one of them has won two rounds.

Am I on the right track or missing something completely?

Can you have more than one if statement in a while loop?

Any help on understanding while loops would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Do you not need to throw the dice inside the loop?

Comment: FYI `rand(1..6)` returns a random number 1 ≤ n ≤ 6 right away, so you don't have to adjust it afterwards.

Comment: What are the rules of each round of the dice game? Are we to figure that out from the code? Please edit to explain how the game works. For example, in each round do both player throw two dice and the winner is the one whose sum of dots on the two dice is greatest? If so, what about ties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you need to throw dices inside the loop.

For example defining a method that returns an array with the two results.

```
def throw_dices
  return rand(1..6), rand(1..6)
end
```

You can assign the result to the variables using [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
player_1, player_2 = throw_dices
```

Once you have the method you can use it inside the loop.

```
player_1_score = 0
player_2_score = 0

while true do
  player_1, player_2 = throw_dices # here is the decomposition
  puts "player_1: #{player_1} - player_2: #{player_2}" # print the throw result or whatever
  player_1_score += 1 if player_1 > player_2
  player_2_score += 1 if player_2 > player_1
  break if player_1_score == 2 || player_2_score == 2
end

p player_1_score
p player_2_score
# do whatever you want with the final score.
```

Note also the use of [abbreviated assignments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment): `player_1_score += 1`